# flutter_uploader on Android does not return 'response' data in listener

Tags: android, flutter

I have setup image uploading using the **flutter_uploader 3.0.0-beta.4** package, and I got it working as advertised on iOS but am unable to get any response data in the returned listener result on Android.

I followed the developers guide to adjust the AndroidManifest.xml file, but those settings kept crashing the Android app build complaining about double starting the WorkManager.
The only way I can even get the app to build for Android is when I use the following  setup in the AndroidManifest file:

```
<application 
...
all default flutter generated settings here
... 
      <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            tools:node="merge">
            <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:exported="false"
                tools:node="remove" />
        </provider>

        <provider
            android:name="com.bluechilli.flutteruploader.FlutterUploaderInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-uploader-init"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.bluechilli.flutteruploader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
                android:value="3" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.bluechilli.flutteruploader.UPLOAD_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS"
                android:value="3600" />
        </provider>
</application>
```

then in Flutter I *enqueue()* the MultipartFormDataUpload() block with the file and some extra data object, all this is sent to PHP and arrives as expected and the file uploads and all data is their in the PHP script, the server-side script then send back a jsonEncoded object, on iOS this json object arrives back in the listeners result.response data, but on Android the response data part is never populated.

```
// UPLOAD IMAGE FILE
queuedPhoto.uploadTaskId = await _uploaderService.enqueue(
  MultipartFormDataUpload(
    url: _httpService.url(EndPoint.uploadPhoto).toString(),
    files: [FileItem(path: filePath, field: "fileToUpload")],
    method: UploadMethod.POST,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    },
    data: {
      "groupPath": groupPath,
      "clientId": '${queuedPhoto.clientId}',
      "projectId": '${queuedPhoto.projectId}',
      "mapId": '${queuedPhoto.mapId}',
      "groupId": '${queuedPhoto.groupId}',
      "userId": '${queuedPhoto.userId}',
      "dateCreated": '${queuedPhoto.dateCreated}',
      "filepath": queuedPhoto.filename,
      "type": queuedPhoto.type,
      "thumbpath": queuedPhoto.thumbnail,
      "note": queuedPhoto.note,
      "lat": queuedPhoto.lat,
      "lon": queuedPhoto.lon,
      "dir": '${queuedPhoto.dir}',
      "tags": queuedPhoto.tags.map((t) => t.name).whereNotNull().toList().join(','),
      "subtags": queuedPhoto.tags
          .map((t) => t.subtag != null ? '${t.subtag?.tagName}_${t.subtag?.name}' : null)
          .whereNotNull()
          .toList()
          .join(','),
      "appVersion": queuedPhoto.appVersion,
      "gpsAccuracy": '${queuedPhoto.gpsAccuracy}',
    },
    tag: filename,
  ),
);
_uploaderService.progress.listen((progress) {
  if (queuedPhoto.uploadTaskId == progress.taskId) {
    queuedPhoto.uploadProgress = progress.progress;
  }
  uploadProgressSubject$.add(progress.progress ?? 0);
});
_uploaderService.result.listen((result) {
  if (queuedPhoto.uploadTaskId == result.taskId && queuedPhoto.uploadProgress == 100) {
    completedUpload(result);
  }
}, onError: (ex, stacktrace) {
  errorUpload();
});
```

the progress listener works as expected, and the result listener also gets result calls (many times during upload with unrelated taskIds, should there be so many unrelated stream results??), the final result that comes through the listener is the one with the correct taskId and all the result object seems correct except there is no result.response object, it always stays null, in the above listener I added a upload progress check to try and limit the result streams to only the final result (I did also check all other results from the seemingly unrelated tasksIds, but for each of them the response data is always null).

Are there any settings I should be changing to the Android config files or should the server-side PHP script return json data in a particular format?

I cant figure this one out, as iOS everything works and on Android all other server-side data GET & POST calls work fine and return the json encoded data that is correctly received and decoded by Android/Flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked out the issue.
Because the flutter_uploader MultipartFormDataUpload() request header is set to something like 'multipart/form-data', my PHP script wasn't resetting the return header's content type to the expected 'application/json;charset=utf-8'.
It worked on iOS, but not on Android.

I fixed my PHP scripts to force the header with the returned data.

```
<?php
  ....
  header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
  echo json_encode($SomeObjectArray);
```